# Reading XML File with DOM parser crashes after first entry

Tags: android, xml, dom

I found many helpfull entries about XML parsing in this forum and then wrote this code to read my XML file from an SD-Card in my Android App.
Unfortunatly it is only returning the first value of  and is crashing after it.

Here my XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="testset">
        <item>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</item>
        <item>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</item>
    </string-array>   
        <string-array name="testsetxy">
        <item>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</item>
        <item>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</item>
    </string-array>  
</resources>
```

And this is the parsing part of my code:

```
public static List<Testset> parse(InputStream is) {
    List<Testset> tsList = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(is);
        Element root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList listNodes = root.getElementsByTagName(NODE);
        Testset testset = new Testset();
        for(int i = 0; i < listNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node curNode = listNodes.item(i);
           String name = ((Attr)(curNode.getAttributes().item(0))).getValue();
              testset.setName(name);
            NodeList listChilds = curNode.getChildNodes();
            List<String> testcases = null;
            for(int j = 0; j < listChilds.getLength(); ++j) {
                Node child = listChilds.item(j);
                if(child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    String childName = child.getNodeName();
                    String childValue = ((Element)child).getTextContent();
                    if(childName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)) {
                        Log.v(TAG, childValue);
                        testcases.add(childValue);
                    }

                    else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "wrong XML format");
                    }
                }
            }
            testset.setTestcases(testcases);
        }
        tsList.add(testset);
        is.close();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        tsList = null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        tsList = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        tsList = null;
    }
    return tsList;
}
```

The Log.v(TAG, childValue); is returning the value of the first  value.

Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in this code :

```
List<Testset> tsList = null;
List<String> testcases = null;
```

you don't initialize  the two lists so you will face `NullExceptionError` after you add first child in testcases `List` so the code `Log` work one time then the exception fired try to initialize your two `List` like that

```
List<Testset> tsList = new ArrayList<Testset>();
List<String> testcases =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

feed me back